# Error After Migrating from .NET3.5 to .NET4.0

Tags: wcf, exception, .net-4.0, fault

I have a test declared as:

```
    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(FaultException<ArgumentException>))]
    public void ShouldNotBeAbleToDeleteASystemList()
```

When I run this in VS2008 targeting .net 3.5 it all works fine and the test passes as the exception is thrown.

I have migrated the solution to VS2010 and changed the target framework to 4.0 and now the test fails with the following details:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ArgumentException,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] was
>   expected

When I write the actual message to the console it is:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ArgumentException]:
>   This is a system list and cannot be
>   deleted (Fault Detail is equal to
>   System.ArgumentException: Value does
>   not fall within the expected range.).

I have checked and all projects are targeting .net 4.0.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who might suffer such a problem. The reason for this error was that the exception was being thrown by a 3rd party component that was compiled against the .net 2.0 framework and the exception thrown was a .net 2.0 class. My code was not interpreting this as the same class. The solution was to change the config of the 3rd party component to add a `<supportedRuntime ... />` line to the `<startup>` section.